# what are all the possible exceptions i can expect when i produce a message onto Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to figure out all the possible exceptions i can expect when i produce a message onto Kafka topic. I looked at the apache producer documentation but didn't find much. so, where can i find the consolidated list of possible exception that a producer can cause/throw?

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Comment: You can catch `KafkaException` which includes (almost) all the exceptions that can occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka producer callback Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654578/kafka-producer-callback-exception)

Comment: Thanks @mike, that helped me. this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks @ThisaruG for your response. I'm looking for more specific details of the exception and i got the list from Mike's post here.