# Kafka producer losing message even if set acks=all

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

This is my config:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "1");
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "1");
```

and

```
try {
    producer.send(record);
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error(ex, "exception.");
}
```

but we found message missing.

if the network dithering will lead this?

do we need to send with Callback?

```
producer.send(record, new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {}
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Kafka Producer has basically three different modes to produce messages to Kafka:

- fire-and-forget
- synchronous
- asynchronous

When only calling `producer.send(record)` you are applying the *fire-and-forget* mode. The configuration `acks` only ensures that the message will be seen as a successful write to Kafka if all replications have acknowledged that message. However, your producer does not wait for the reply.

As you have mentioned, you could make use of a callback to understand the reply from the broker. This will be the *asychronous* mode. But do not forget to also `flush()` the buffered records.

Another option would be to apply the *synchronous* which can be achieved by a blocking method `get` that waits for the ack-response from the broker. You only have to change the only line of code to

```java
producer.send(record).get();
```

Edit: It might be worth increasing the retries to a number larger than `1`. The Producer `Callback` can return *retrieable* exceptions which could be solved with more than one retry. To understand all callback exceptions you can have a look at another SO question on [Producer Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654578/kafka-producer-callback-exception/61659196#61659196).